# Oauth 1.0a stops working after upgrading from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework, playframework-2.4

I recently upgraded from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4.

All API requests to Yelp used to work with Play 2.3 as follows.

```
WS.url("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?radius_filter=20000&term=" +
    URLEncoder.encode(store.name, "UTF-8") + "&location=" + 
    URLEncoder.encode(store.address, "UTF-8")))
  .sign(OAuthCalculator(ConsumerKey(YELP_CONSUMER_KEY, YELP_CONSUMER_SECRET), RequestToken(YELP_TOKEN, YELP_TOKEN_SECRET)))
  .get
```

After upgrading to Play 2.4, I get signature invalid error from Yelp.

Anything new I need to do? I do see that OAuth signature calculator is changed in Play 2.4. Thanks.

Comment: What's the resulting URL? (You can censor the key and secret.) You're right, [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3955) for this.

Comment: How do I find the resulting URL? I dumped WSRequest.url, and it shows NingWSRequest(NingWSClient(com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig@48bf4cc4),http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?radius_filter=20000&term=BJ%27s+Restaurant+%26+Brewhouse&location=2624+S.+Shackleford+Rd.+Little+Rock%2C+AR.+72205,GET,EmptyBody,Map(),Map(),Some(play.api.libs.oauth.OAuthCalculator@4706d5dc),None,None,None,None,None,None).url, not very useful. WSResponse doesn't have anything about url.

Comment: Replace `.get` with `.url` to see the resulting URL.

Comment: That is what I did, append .url to my WSRequest. It didn't show a plain string. NingWSRequest(NingWSClient(com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig@732bc916), http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?radius_filter=20000&term=BJ%27s+Restaurant+%26+Brewhouse&location=2624+S.+Shackleford+Rd.+Little+Rock%2C+AR.+72205, GET,EmptyBody,Map(),Map(),Some(play.api.libs.oauth.OAuthCalculator@77bb63ff),None,None,None,None,None,None).url

Comment: Ok, this time I didn't use Scala string interpolation. There is no key or secret in the url. It shows: http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?radius_filter=20000&term=BJ%27s+Restaurant+%26+Brewhouse&location=2624+S.+Shackleford+Rd.+Little+Rock%2C+AR.+72205

Comment: @bjfletcher, any comment?

Comment: Hey :) Thinking... try printing out `.headers` and seeing if the signature header is in, and see what it looks like.

Comment: Hi, WSRequest.headers contains nothing, but if I cast WSRequest into NingWSRequest and print out .requestHeaders, I get this:
Map(Authorization -> Buffer(OAuth oauth_consumer_key="censored", oauth_token="censored", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="qo1bf5j5npHukXeT0a8c75M%2FBk%3D", oauth_timestamp="1436388525", oauth_nonce="c82adLqlAb0ZI4Clo%2BM9Q%3D%3D", oauth_version="1.0"))

Comment: I'd go back to the old setup that worked, look to see if there's any difference with the URL and headers. I'd also post a new question on Stack Overflow with just the URL and the headers, tag it with OAuth and maybe Yell, then hopefully non-Scala/Play OAuth people can help.

Comment: I think they broke oauth in play 2.4.. only bug I see is https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/4778 which seems not right

Comment: Thanks @bwawok. I made a comment on request #4826.